# Insert to mysql with PHP and AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, insert

I try to make a form for updating status (select) with AJAX. What I have is:

HTML + JS:

```
<select id="Bname">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var sel = document.getElementById('Bname');

  sel.addEventListener("change", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {

  jQuery.ajax({
            url         : "insert.php",
            type        : "post",
            contentType : 'application/json',
            dataType    : 'json',
            data        : {
                stat : sel.value
            }
        })
    .done(function() {
    console.warn('ok!');
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.warn('error');
  });

  console.log(sel.value);

}
</script>
```

In insert.php file I have:

```
<?php
  defined('_JEXEC') or die;

  $stat = $_POST["stat"];

  $db = JFactory::getDbo();

  $query = $db->getQuery(true);

  $fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('cars') . ' = ' . $db->quote($stat)
  );

  $conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 1'
  );

  $query->update($db->quoteName('#__cars'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

  $db->setQuery($query);

  $result = $db->execute();

?>
```

Question is – why PHP file is not inserting? Any kind of script in insert.php isn't working. It's made with Joomla.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors or checked the error log file for `php`?

Comment: Does `sel.value` contain anything? Is that the correct way of getting a select value?

Comment: check first printing the post by using print_r($_POST); exit; If it's not coming then we need to debug at client side first, and if coming then we'll look at server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import the joomla libraries if you are calling ajax with single file.